# Would we observe beats if the ratio of the frequencies of two waves is irrational?

Tags: waves, acoustics, superposition

For Example, Would we observe beats for a 540 Hz sound wave and a 545.879614.....(irrational) wave? Though they lie within 10Hz of each other, their sum would not produce a periodic function so I don't think they will form a beat. If I'm wrong please correct me and provide the beat frequency of these two waves.

Comment: The beat frequency would be the difference between the two frequencies as the term irrational is a mathematical concept which does not translate fully into Physics. An infinite number of significant figures has no meaning in Physics

Answer (score 3):

The whole wave will not be periodic but it will go from minima to minima in every $\frac {1}{545.879614-540}$ $s$. The frequency of the amplitude of the wave going from minima to minima is the best frequency.

Although the beat frequency is irrational, it does not matter, as one second is nothing special, and nothing prevents "the number of beats per second" to be an irrational number.

Check this graph. The red graph is the amplitude, and blue graph is intensity, which is not periodic, but goes to zero periodically.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3walg7xdsk[enter link description here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3walg7xdsk)
[image]

Comment: But beats are produced because the superposed resultant of two waves is periodic. The superposed resultant of two waves whose frequency ratio is irrational isn't periodic. Hence, we shouldn't get a beat.

Comment: They are periodic, the math tells so. Note that $n$ is irrational does not mean $2\pi n t $ cannot be a integer multiple of $2\pi$

Comment: If the ratio of the frequencies is irrational then the sum is not

Comment: What it merely tells is that the time period of beats cannot be rational. But time need not be rational, it can be irrational

Comment: The time period of a beat is the time taken for one function that is n phases ahead of another function to get n+1 phases ahead of it. With an irrational ratio, this would never happen.

Comment: Time period of beats is the time period of the sum of the two waves. Irrational ratio means the resulting function isn't periodic.

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: The Minima will be the local minima. No two minima would have the same value. Thus, we can't call that as a period.

Comment: When you hear the beats, you hear the intensity, whose minima is always zero, at constant intervals.

Comment: I am going to provide a graphical example